# How to check/uncheck checkbox inside child of child "li" using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to check the check box ".chkGroup" by li "#parentLi".

```
<li id="parentLi">
    <span class="collapsible"></span>
    <span>System</span>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="collapsible"></span>
            <span>Division</span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input class="chkGroup" type="checkbox">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: post your jquery code as well. which you have tried.

Comment: What's the issue here? Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
$(function(){
  $('li').click(function(){
    $('#parentLi').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li id="parentLi">
    <span class="collapsible"></span>
    <span>System</span>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="collapsible"></span>
            <span>Division</span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input class="chkGroup" type="checkbox">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you. this is the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this below code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#parentLi input.chkGroup").prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="parentLi">
    <span class="collapsible"></span>
    <span>System</span>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="collapsible"></span>
            <span>Division</span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input class="chkGroup" type="checkbox">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

try following `jQuery` code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#parentLi').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName != 'INPUT') {
      $(this).find('input').prop('checked', function(i, checked) {
        return !checked
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="parentLi">
    <span class="collapsible"></span>
    <span>System</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="collapsible"></span>
        <span>Division</span>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input class="chkGroup" type="checkbox">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```